# My code is not working and it missing something for the array

Tags: c#

```
string[] names = { "Al Dente", "Anna Graham", "Earle Bird", "Ginger Rayle", "Iona Ford" };

int i = 0;
while (i < names.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine(names[0]);
}
```

why is my code not working I feel its something very simple to modify I want it to output them calling it names. What am I missing?

Comment: You never exits from the loop because the variable i is always zero

Comment: usually you would use a for loop incrementing i and accessing the array at i... or you could use a foreach loop... at the moment you have an infinite loop printing the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (i < names.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
    i++;
}
```

You can also try the shorter version

```
foreach(var name in names)
    Console.WriteLine(name);
```

or even

```
names.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

You never exit from the loop because the variable i is never incremented and thus is always zero

```
string[] names = { "Al Dente", "Anna Graham", "Earle Bird", "Ginger Rayle", "Iona Ford" };

int i = 0;
while (i < names.Length)
{
    // Write the i-th element of the array
    Console.WriteLine(names[i]);

    // Increment i of one to allow the loop to exit when i reaches the names.Length value
    i++;
}
```

then you want surely print the i element of the array at each loop so use **names[i]**

To avoid these problems then you could use a foreach loop

```
foreach(string s in names)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `Console.WriteLine(names[i]);`, with names[i] rather than names[0]. You also aren't incrementing i! Something like:

```
string[] names = { "Al Dente", "Anna Graham", "Earle Bird", "Ginger Rayle", "Iona Ford" };

int i = 0;
while (i < names.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use **for**:

```
string[] names = { "Al Dente", "Anna Graham", "Earle Bird", "Ginger Rayle", "Iona Ford" };

for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is recommended to create a reference for the array like this

```
string[] names = new string[] { "Al Dente", "Anna Graham", "Earle Bird", "Ginger Rayle", "Iona Ford" };
```

but your mistake here is in the loop, you have to make a counter that increments or decrements like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < names.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
    i++;
}
```

OR, if you want ot print names in REVERSE order :

```
int i = names.Length;
while (i > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
    i--;
}
```